# FLASH component not showing - blank white region insted

Tags: flash, http-headers

from time to time I get feedback from my web portal customers that they cannot see Flash component on the page - instead there's a blank white region.

When it happens I instruct them to clear browser cache, and it solves the issue. Is there any way to handle this differently, using HTTP headers etc. ?

Thanks,Pawel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the real reason for this happening is the cache problem, then you should add to the swf you calling in HTML:

`content.swf?154964879684654` -> which is some random number ( Seconds since the Unix Epoch or sesionID )

then it will be forced to load the swf as new one.